# Multistage Dockefile - how to copy/install dependencies the right way

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, uvicorn

I build a python web application with a multistage docker with a Jenkins job. In one stage of the Jenkins job, the `builder` is installing all the deps into a folder (i.e `pip install --target deps`). These are getting copied into the Docker image with the corresponding `ENV PYTHONPATH=deps:.`. However, when I want to start something that is on `PATH` (e.g. `uvicorn`) the error message is: `sh uvicorn not found` when I start the Docker image with the Python application. I even added the `deps/bin` to PATH but it still fails. What am I doing wrong ? Building the image without the deps stage and just installing a venv solves the whole issue.

To understand it the relevant code for the Makefile and the Dockerfile are below

```
FROM Python:3.9-slim as base
ENV  PYTHONPATH=deps:.


FROM base as builder 

RUN --mount=type=cache,id=apt-cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,id=apt-lib,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
    apt-get update && apt-get --no-install-recommends install -y build-essential

FROM base 

COPY deps deps
COPY app app

CMD [uvicorn, app.main:app, --host 0.0.0.0, --port 8000]
```

Makefile below

```
build:
       docker build --tag app:builder .

deps: clean
         mkdir deps
         pip install -r requirements.txt --target deps

clean: 
         rm  -rf deps
```

```
Jenkins-Job
1. Trigger to build the builder
2. Trigger that the builder builds the deps stage in the makefile
3. Docker build the Docker image with the application
```

The sketched project structure looks as follows

```
│   requirements.txt
├── app
│   ├── models
│   │   └── registry
│   ├── api_router.py
│   ├── configuration.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── schemas
│   │ 
│   └── tests
│       └── unit
└── docs
```

However, just adding the deps folder to `ENV PYTHONPATH = deps:.` did not help. The dependencies are not found when prompting `pip list -v`, however with `pip freeze` they are listed.

Comment: Hi. Please read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section.

Comment: I added some code snippets. I hole they are sufficient to describe the problem from the code side.

Comment: It's not obvious what you're trying to do here: you're not actually using multiple build stages; your first stage (`FROM Python:3.9-slim as base`) doesn't do anything; you could remove `FROM base as builder` and you would end up with exactly the same configuration. I don't see where you're calling `pip install` here, so it makes sense that you're getting a "command not found" error trying to call `uvicorn`.

Comment: so the pip install is called during the Jenkins job. Jenkins does basically have the pipeline with the deps stage defined where it just pip installs the relevant data into the deps folder that is then copied to the main image.

Comment: All we know is what you show in your question, and for what you've shown here it's clear that there's nothing in your Dockerfile that would install `uvicorn` into a directory in your `$PATH`. You say, "I even added `deps/bin` to PATH", but you don't show us that, nor do you show us the contents of `deps/bin`. If you can update this question to include a [mcve] will be able to provide much more effective help.

Comment: I have updated the description. With a bit more help I think I can add more info that is needed for the minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with this Dockerfile.

1. The initial `FROM` line is using the wrong image name; if you try to build an image from this Dockerfile it will fail with:

   ```
   ERROR: failed to solve: failed to parse stage name "Python:3.9-slim":
   invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
   ```
2. As discussed in the comments, there are a bunch of pointless build stages. They're not contributing anything to the build process and can be removed.
3. The syntax `CMD [uvicorn, app.main:app, --host 0.0.0.0, --port 8000]` is incorrect. When attempting to run a container from that image, it will fail with:

   ```
   /bin/sh: 1: [uvicorn,: not found
   ```

   We need to write it with proper quoting (see below).
4. Because you're installing dependencies *outside* of the container, scripts (like `deps/bin/uvicorn`) will probably have the wrong path to the Python interpreter.

If we resolve all of the above issues, we end up with a Dockerfile that looks like:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim as base

ENV  PYTHONPATH=deps

COPY deps deps
COPY app app

# We call python3 explicitly here to deal with the fact that deps/bin/uvicorn
# probably has the wrong path to python3.
CMD ["python3", "./deps/bin/uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

If we build an image from this Dockerfile and run it, it works:

```
$ docker build -t deps-example .
...
$ docker run --rm deps-example
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

---

While the above works, it's not how one would usually dockerize a Python application. A more typical setup would install dependencies inside the container (which would eliminate path related problems). E.g., we might have this layout instead:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim as base

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @larsk. The stages for docker are solving some cashing problems and also disk sizes. The images are internal ones, that I dont want to disclose here. Following this will lead to a messed up Pythonpath that I could not resolve in the beginning but with a imagesize that is 3x smaller.

Comment: Well, the solutions presented here will work even if you maintain the multiple build stages.